# Cannot mock federated module within jest file in host application even with virtual mock

Tags: unit-testing, webpack, jestjs, webpack-module-federation, testing-library

I am trying to mock a federated module within a test like so:

within my JS file:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-unresolved
import { EventBus } from 'federated-module/main';
```

within its corresponding test file

```
jest.mock('federated-module/main', () => ({
  EventBus: () => void
}), { virtual: true });
```

when I run the test I am receiving this error:

```
● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'federated-module/main' from 'path-to-file-using-modlue-federated-import/index.js'
```

is there any extra setup I may need to do within my jest config?